# Syntax error on token ";" in Java

Tags: java

"Syntax error on token ";", Primitive Type expected after this token" is the message i get rite after the semi colon on this statement `"String data = input.next(); "` and i don't know why.

```
import java.util.*;
public class PorterHouse {
    public static void main(String[] args){
System.out.println("enter interest rate, loan mount, and number of years: ex. "+
    " 7.9-400000-5");
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

String data = input.next(); 

[] b = data.split("[-]");
double interstRate = Double.parseDouble(b[0]);
double loanPrincipal = Double.parseDouble(b[1]);
double loanLength = Double.parseDouble(b[2]);
double monthlyPayment = (b[1]*b[2] / 1);
double totalPayment = ( monthlyPayment * loanLength * 12);
System.out.println("Monthly Pament: " + monthlyPayment);
System.out.println("totalPayment: " + totalPayment);


}
}
```

Comment: `[] b` has no data type.

Answer (score 2):

Try to change this:

```
[] b = data.split("[-]");
```

with this:

```
string[] b = data.split("[-]");
```

Presently `[] b` has no data type. So do provide a data type to it.

Comment: And the reason for down vote is ?

Comment: thanks it lead me to another problem also.

Answer (score 1):

I guess instead of :

```
[] b = data.split("[-]");
```

you need something like :

```
String[] b = data.split("[-]");
```

also

you might wanna replace :

```
double monthlyPayment = (b[1]*b[2] / 1);
```

by :

```
double monthlyPayment = (loanPrincipal * loanLength  / 1); //idk why divide by 1??
```

cuz, `b[1]` and `b[2]` are two Strings.